# How to print a huge string

Tags: c, printf

I'm a beginner and I need to know how to print an entire help page in C.

I am trying:

```
unsigned short * entireHelpPage;
unsigned int * someString:
printf("comparing %s to %s", someString, entireHelpPage);
```

this is printing something like this :

```
comparing Dog to Dog is a domestic animal.. blah blah.. Dogs are bred in mos
```

As you will see that entireHelpPage is not getting displayed completely when I try to print it.

Please let me know how to get it to print the entire help page.

Comment: Why are you using `short` and `int` pointers for strings?

Comment: read C tutorial.there you will found how to declare and print string.

Comment: I am going through the source code of an application. Its pre written like that.. If I change it then I will get errors on 100 different places.

Comment: What kind of "application" is this? Can you share more of its code? Here is an example that works: http://ideone.com/0acjzu

Comment: I am not facing problems in printing the string. My problem goes like this:
the second string is big. its like a page. a help page. my code is unable to print the page completely. its only printing a part of it.

now my question is: 
how do I get it to print my entire page

Comment: Until which point does your code print the string? How are you sure it is bigger than what is being printed?

Comment: On which platform are you running this application?

Comment: What is `strlen(entireHelpPage)`? Where are you viewing results? Have you tried to redirect output to file? Is `printf` function comes from standard libc or it's custom? It's because printf have just no problems printing multilines, so if it's from some widespread libc - the problem is on other side.

Comment: Are you just saying that the text disappears off the edge of the screen? Or is it displaying only a certain number of characters?

Comment: If my page is of a 1000 characters then its only printing like 400
I am running this C program under Linux environment
the printf function is from std libc and yes the text just disappears half way through the printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to get around limitation in `printf()` or potential memory/display problem.

OP is experiencing *some* issue.  `printf()` should be able to print at least 4095 characters before it has troubles.  To get around a non-conforming issue, use a loop.  To find unexpected non-printable characters, print them out in a special fashion.

```
const char *s = (const char *) entireHelpPage;
fputs(">", stdout);
while (*s) {
  if (isgraph(*s)) {
    fputc(*s, stdout);
    }
  else {
    fprintf(stdout, "[%02X]", (unsigned) *s);
    }
  s++;
}
fputs("<\n", stdout);
```

Further: it is strange to use `unsigned short *` as a pointer to `char*` data.  I suspect that the tailing memory pointer to by `entireHelpPage` is being unexpectedly over-written by code.  It could be that `entireHelpPage` is a buffer about 400 bytes and is simple not larger enough for the help page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I'm not able to comprehend this completely because I'm a beginner and I thought there would be a simpler way to do it. I just want to print my HelpPage to the stdout